# Azure Devops, how to create release with arm template which deploys a storage account and associate it with appsettings

Tags: azure-devops

we have automated the following steps using azure devops

1. A Release pipeline which creates a website in azure and the next step which deploys the code, all is well and working so far

The next step that we need to do is create a Azure SQLDB and and an Azure Storage Account in the release pipeline and then configure these values in the appsettings.json file

Questions

1. Creating the Storage account is the easy part, but how do we get the storage account key back in the pipeline and associate that value in the appsetting.json file ?
2. Similarly for the SQLDB how do we get the IPAddress and add it in the exclusions list.

and also it you could point us to any documentation on this

Answer (score 0):

> how do we get the storage account key back in the pipeline.

You can use the Azure CLI [az storage account keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/account/keys?view=azure-cli-latest) to get storage account keys.